# Property based searches in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

While looking for the best way to search an array of objects in Javascript (there doesn't seem to be a iterate + compare function for that) I came [across this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913672/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-some-items-in-an-array-based-on-the-item-property-va) which seems like are really elegant way of doing this.

However I have some questions:

1. Javascript doesn't have associative arrays. These seems like one. What gives?
2. This seems like a very elegant solution but how does it stack up against the competition?

   - "Pass the array and comparison function" - means several specific comparison functions for various searches.
   - "Optimised findByX functions" - means optimised searches for each type needed.
   - "[scalalala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913672/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-some-items-in-an-array-based-on-the-item-property-va) method" - which I suspect would be the slowest but most elegant.

Also how would you go about taking a reponse from AJAX and creating an array with a similar structure to this? Most tutorials hand-pick and roll the examples to demonstrate the associativity of arrays but not how that could be used practically.

Is there any pitfalls to using this method?

Decent links ([beyond this](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays)) would be appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
This is what I am having trouble with. If I have data coming back from the server similar to this:

```
$.getJSON("map.php?jsoncallback=?", function(data) {
    for (var x=0,xx=data.stars.length; x<xx; x++) {
        stars.push( 
            new Star(
                data.stars[x].id,
                data.stars[x].xpos, data.stars[x].ypos,
                data.stars[x].name, data.stars[x].owner
            )
        );
    }
});
```

Where Star is a class:

```
function Star(id, x, y, n, o) {
    this.id = id;
    this.x = x; this.y = y;
    this.name = n;  this.owner = o;
}
```

**So how do I turn this into the "associative" style array?**

Comment: It isn't using associative arrays, but arrays of objects, which are entirely different. You're right in that JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays

Comment: Simple javascript objects can be treated as associative arrays (or more accurately, hashmaps) as long as the key is string.

Comment: I'd avoid extending the Array prototype and instead write a utility function/object/constructor to *"encapsulate"* the find by x functionality required for arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript Array objects should be used with numeric sequential indexes, but you can use plain objects, that are simply a collection of key/value pairs.

In the code you link, the function looks for an object inside an array.

Note that this code has jQuery as a dependency (it uses `$.grep`).

For performance I would recommend you to use the standard [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/filter) method, modern browsers provide a *native implementations* that is **really fast**, compared to a custom implementation.

For compatibility (mostly for IE), you can include the method implementation on the above link.

This method is really easy to use, and is now part of the [ECMAScript 5th Edition Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) (PDF) (*Section 15.4.4.20*):

```
var filtered = existingArray.filter(function (obj) {
  return obj.property == someValue;
});
```

The above code will give you back a new *filtered* array with all the objects that match the condition specified in the `filter` callback function.

Comment: Since you gave most information, though not all the answers, you get the tick.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, all objects are collections of name-value pairs.  If you want to iterate through the collection of properties of an object, look at this code:

```
for (var key in object) {
    alert(key + ':' + object[key]);
}
```

If you want to filter out the inherited properties:

```
for(var key in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        alert(key + ':' + object[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: So I can't have `{ name: "scala",  type: "a",  diff: "hard" }` or can I?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the object you wrote-out in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to add the filter command if it doesn't exist for IE compatibility:

```
if (!new Array().filter) Array.prototype.filter = function (fnCallback) {
  var ret = new Array();
  var j = 0;
  for (var obj in this)
    if (fnCallback(obj)) ret[j++] = obj;
  return obj;
};
```

Comment: I'm new to the site. how do I get it to put the gray area for the code instead of it making it all one line?

Comment: You select the code and click on the curly bracket icon above the editor. Alternatively, you can use backticks to get the same effect with `text` surrounded by other text. Also, check out the help info on the right when you're editing.